# Continuous functions with respect to a topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let X be a non-empty set and let $x_0 \in X$. The topology $T$ is defined by the collection of subsets $U \subset X$ such that either $U = \emptyset$ or $U \ni x_0$.

Is it true that if $f: X \rightarrow X$ is continuous, does it follow that $f(x_0)=x_0$ with respect to the topology $T$?

I under stand that the converse is true, that is for any function $f: X \rightarrow X$ with $f(x_0)=x_0$ is continuous with respect to the topology T but i don't know how to prove if this case is true.

Comment: It should be $U = \{x_0\}$, not $U=x_0$. Also $T$ is not a topology if it doesn't include $X$.

Comment: @jjagmath They possibly meant $U\ni x_0$?

Comment: @FShrike That would be also my guess.

Comment: does that make sense now?

Comment: User: you made an edit to “$U\in x_0$” but I assume you meant $U\ni x_0$: the correct command is `\ni`

Answer (score 2):

No:  consider a constant map to a point that is not $x_0$.

These are in fact the only counterexamples to your claim.  Suppose $f: X \to X$ is continuous.  If $x_0 \in \mathrm{im}(f)$ then $\{x_0\}$ is an open set in the codomain with non-empty preimage, and from this you can easily see that $f(x_0)=x_0$.  If $x_0 \notin \mathrm{im}(f)$ then it is a good exercise to show that $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is discrete in the subspace topology inherited from $X$.  But $\mathrm{im}(f)$ must also be connected since $X$ is, and a connected discrete space must consist of only one point.  Hence $f$ is constant.